# Simple URL rewriting gone wrong

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I have this `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^feed/sejururi\.xml$ /feed/ [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What I want is if someone accesses the URL `example.com/feed/sejururi.xml` to show him the content of `example.com/feed`.

However now the website shows a 404 not found error on `example.com/feed/sejururi.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

First I would take it out from the Wordpress block rules, as it will be overwrited when permalinks are refreshed if you don't add the rule to Rewrite API.

Then you could add at the bottom of your htaccess something like:

```
Redirect 301 feed/sejururi.xml http://yoursite.com/feed/
```

Comment: gives still a 404

Comment: i would not go on a "redirect" but on a "rewrite" ... i need the url to stay the same while the user sees the same as on the orher link

Comment: If you try http://yoursite.com/feed/ that url actually works?

Comment: What you are getting by directly accessing url http://yoursite.com/feed/ ?

Comment: I am getting the correct feed and it loads correctly.